# Swift Package Manager (SPM): Error importing library

Tags: swift

I'm facing problems while importing a library I created.

This is the `Package.swift` of my `executable`:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
  name: "PayBackCodingChallenge",
  dependencies: [
    .package(url: "../NumberChecker", from: "1.0.0"),
  ],
  targets: [
    .target(
      name: "PayBackCodingChallenge",
      dependencies: []),
  ]
)
```

When I try to `import NumberChecker` in my `main.swift` I get the following message: **No such module 'NumberChecker'**:

```
import NumberChecker

let arguments = CommandLine.arguments

if arguments.count != 3 {
  print("USAGE: PayBackCodingChallenge [data] [target]")
  print("  data: File containing list of numbers ")
  print("  target: Target number")
} else {
  let data = arguments[1]
  let target = arguments[2]
  print(data + " " + target)
}
```

My NumberChecker library is located in a directory at the same level as PayBackCodingChallenge and compiles correctly. What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `NumberChecker` as a dependency to `PayBackCodingChallenge`:

`...
  targets: [
    .target(
      name: "PayBackCodingChallenge",
      dependencies: ["NumberChecker"]),
  ]
  ...`